# PyQt: Setting CompositionMode for QGraphicsItems (e.g. Multiply)

Tags: pyqt, qgraphicsview

I tried this by reimplementing drawItems in `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`, but nothing happens (it says to set the `IndirectPainting` Flag, but this gives me an error). Using the composition mode within one painter works fine, but I don't know how to apply it to all graphicsitems.

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsScene::drawItems` is not called since Qt 4.6. The flag `IndirectPainting` is just here for compatibility